# Redirect from https to http url stored from google

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https

in a search from google , i found my domain url with https and not http . 
For example : https://xxxx.com/yyyy/zzzz and not http://xxxx.com/yyyy/zzzz
It's possible redirect from https to http for the domain xxxx.com ?
I use centos and apache web server 
On the same server, i have a certificate https that respond to https://zzzz.com 
Thanks

Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with mod_rewrite on. Put this code in .htaccess file at root of the site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```